# MYSQL Query same column with AND and OR conditions

Tags: mysql, relational-division

I have the following tables:

```
       Topic                 Content_Topic                Content

id_topic   topic         id_content   id_topic     id_content  content
    1      aaaaa             1            2             1        xxxxx
    2      bbbbb             1            4             2        yyyyy
    3      ccccc             1            5             3        zzzzz
    4      ddddd             2            1             4        wwwww
    5      eeeee             2            3             5        kkkkk
    6      fffff             2            5             6        jjjjj
        ...                  3            3                  ...
                             3            4 
                             3            5 
                                  ...
```

I'm trying to run the following query but I'm not obtaining what I expect:

```
SELECT content FROM Content_Topic ct
LEFT JOIN Content c ON ct.id_content=c.id_topic
LEFT JOIN Topic t ON ct.id_topic=t.id_topic
WHERE   (ct.id_topic=2 OR ct.id_topic=3) AND 
        ct.id_topic IN (4,7,10) AND 
        (ct.id_topic=5 OR ct.id_topic=9)
```

What I expect is to have all content that have id_topic 2,4,5 or 3,4,5 or 2,7,5 or 3,7,5 and so on... I receive instead a void result.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a special type of relational division. That is, you're looking for content that matches a set of topics, where each element has alternates.

You can't do this only with a condition in a `WHERE` clause, because the condition is evaluated for one row at a time. There is no value of `id_topic` on a given row that is both 2 and 4 and 5 at the same time.

You need a condition on sets of rows, and this is what relational division is.

In your case, I'd do it with joins. By using joins, you can make three references to *different* rows of Content_Topic, so the conditions can be mutually exclusive.

```
SELECT c.content
FROM Content c
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct1 
  ON c.id_content=ct1.id_content AND ct1.id_topic IN (2,3)
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct2 
  ON c.id_content=ct2.id_content AND ct2.id_topic IN (4,7,10)
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct3
  ON c.id_content=ct3.id_content AND ct3.id_topic IN (5,9)
```

This query must matches a content to three topics. If it doesn't match all three, the content won't be returned by the query.

But each of the three has alternates.

Comment: Also this query works with some correction. INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct1 should change in INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct2, INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct3...
but I'm not sure if ct1.id_topic IN (2,3) is the same of (ct1.id_topic=2 OR ct1.id_topic=3)

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's a consequence of copying and pasting. I'll fix it.

Comment: Yes, the `IN(...)` predicate is exactly the same as several `OR` terms, assuming each term is comparing with `=`.

Comment: Thank you. Just to add a bit, I added also a DISTINCT since the query generates duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying (2 or 3) AND (4 or 7 or 10) AND (5 or 9)

What that means is you'll never get any results.

```
y = 2 or 3

x = 4, 7 or 10

z = 5 or 9
```

It's impossible to make `x AND y` be true in that case.

I would use table aliases to reference your Content_Topic table 3 times so you can make each of your criteria work and I would use Joins and not sub-selects because it's faster:

```
SELECT content FROM Content c 
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct1 ON ct1.id_content=c.id_topic AND (ct1.id_topic=2 OR ct1.id_topic=3)
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct2 ON ct2.id_content=c.id_topic AND (ct2.id_topic IN (4,7,10))
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct3 ON ct3.id_content=c.id_topic AND (ct3.id_topic=5 OR ct3.id_topic=9)
```

Comment: If this way is not possible, do you know a different way to manage it? Thank you for your help

Comment: See my edits for what I think you want - it's untested and if you want a working example setup an sqlfiddle and provide a link

Comment: *`FROM Content c .. ON .. =c.id_topic`* Where have you found it? No `id_topic` field in `Content` table.

Comment: This seems to works and seems the best solution. I did some corrections and changes: ct1.id_content=c.id_topic to ct1.id_content=c.id_content and I added a DISTINCT since there were duplicates. If ok and you modify your answer, I accept it as solution.

SELECT DISTINCT(c.id_content), c.* FROM Content c 
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct1 ON ct1.id_content=c.id_content AND (ct1.id_topic=2 OR ct1.id_topic=3)
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct2 ON ct2.id_content=c.id_content AND (ct2.id_topic IN (4,7,10))
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct3 ON ct3.id_content=c.id_content AND (ct3.id_topic=5 OR ct3.id_topic=9)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would be easier done with aggregation and a `HAVING` clause for filtering:

```
SELECT c.content 
FROM Content c
INNER JOIN Content_Topic ct ON ct.id_content = c.id_content
GROUP BY c.id_content, c.content
HAVING
    -- 2, 4, 5
    (MAX(c.id_topic = 2) = 1 AND MAX(c.id_topic = 4) = 1 AND MAX(c.id_topic = 5) = 1)
    -- 3, 4, 5
    OR (MAX(c.id_topic = 3) = 1 AND MAX(c.id_topic = 4) = 1 AND MAX(c.id_topic = 5) = 1)
    -- 2, 5, 7
    OR (MAX(c.id_topic = 2) = 1 AND MAX(c.id_topic = 5) = 1 AND MAX(c.id_topic = 7) = 1)
    -- add more if needed ...
```

This will give you all `content`s that either have topics 2, 3 and 5, OR topics 3, 4, and 5, OR topics 2, 5 and 7. You can extend the `HAVING` clause with more `OR` conditions as needed.

Another thing to notice is that you don't actually need to bring in the `Topic` table for that task (the information you want is available in `Content_Topic`).

Comment: This works, but in HAVING cluase you are using the result as id_topics and I didn't know the result before doing the query

Answer (score -1):

I think your joining condition is going wrong -

```
SELECT content
FROM Content_Topic ct
LEFT JOIN Content c ON ct.id_content=c.id_content
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Topic T
              WHERE T.id_topic = ct.Content_Topic
              AND ct.id_topic IN (2, 3))
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Topic T1
            WHERE T1.id_topic = ct.Content_Topic
            AND ct.id_topic IN (4,7,10))
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Topic T2
            WHERE T2.id_topic = ct.Content_Topic
            AND ct.id_topic IN (5, 9))
```

Comment: Use joins instead of sub-selects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Content_Topic ct1
JOIN Content c1 ON ct`.id_content=c`.id_topic
JOIN ( SELECT id_content
       FROM Content_Topic ct
       LEFT JOIN Content c ON ct.id_content=c.id_topic
       LEFT JOIN Topic t ON ct.id_topic=t.id_topic
       GROUP BY id_content
       HAVING SUM(ct.id_topic IN (2,3)) > 0
          AND SUM(ct.id_topic IN (4,7,10)) > 0
          AND SUM(ct.id_topic IN (5,9)) > 0 
     ) sq ON ct.id_content = ct1.id_content
```

Comment: Use joins instead of sub-selects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query